# jquery add delay to animation

Tags: jquery, delayed-execution

I am trying to add a delay to my Jquery so that once the mouse leaves my div id=test it will wait 3000 ms before closing back up. It doesnt seem to be working however?

I am using Jquery 1.6.min

Thank you in advance for your help and code snippets

```
$("#test").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '10'});
    $(this).addClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            height: '60px'
        }, 1500);

    } , function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
    $(this).delay(3000);
    $(this).removeClass("hover").stop() 
        .animate({
            height: '20px'
        }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Use jsfiddle to give an example seriously, people using this site need to start doing that

Comment: Agreed but I don't think we should 'sue' the site!

Comment: I made this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/7NrPA/1/ edit it to more closely match your context and then add it to your question. @Russ C Yeah, probably not =p

Comment: Luck us I do have one http://jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/1430/

Comment: I updated your fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/1433/, chaining the calls makes it all work.

Comment: I just checked and I dont see the delay?

Comment: Thank for all your help, I got http://jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/1436/ to do what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to just chain the calls together in the second block, or they run asynchronously :

```
$("#test").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '10'});
    $(this).addClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            height: '60px'
        }, 1500);

    } , function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'})
       .delay(3000)
       .removeClass("hover")
       .stop() 
       .animate({
            height: '20px'
        }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: One small problem is its doing the yo-yo trick if you mouse out then back in before its done

Comment: working off of yours and Mark I was able to get it to do what I needed http://jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/1436/  Thank everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

wild guess is that you should be using chaining in order to make delay effective

alternatively, in "leave handler", you could use something like this:

```
function(){ setTimeout(function(){ .. perform what you need}, 3000);}
```

Comment: I tried something like that and came up with `$("#test").hover(function() {
 $(this).css({'z-index' : '10'});
 $(this).addClass("hover").stop()
  .animate({
   height: '60px'
  }, 1500);

 } , function() {
 $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
 $(this).removeClass("hover").stop() 
  setTimeout(
  .animate({
   height: '20px'
  }, 1500);
  , 500);
});`
but that didnt seem to work

Comment: see above. chaining should do it well enough.

Answer (score 1):

You had .delay in the wrong spot. Here is the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

You should have used the code:

```
$(this).removeClass("hover").stop().delay(3000) 
    .animate({
        height: '20px'
    }, 1500);
```

And here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/7NrPA/3/